# Ansible - run list of tasks until success

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there a way to run a block of tasks until successful condition?
This  is what I am trying to achieve:

```
 - start sequence below
      task running shell command to generate kerberos ticket
      task wait_for_connection
   retry sequence x times until wait_for connection is successful
```

What is the best way to achieve it?It seems that 'block' is not designed for this purpose..

Comment: Yes I looked at docs for block and looping

Comment: Correct  - the first link I get is Ansible documentation for Looping.

Comment: The section you mentioned refers to a single task. I need to run two tasks in a sequence.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I mentioned “ block of tasks” and my example shows two tasks

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: No problem:) Hopefully I will be able to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no solution. "include_tasks" could help if "until" works with "include_tasks". Not the case https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17098

There is a feature request open: "until for blocks" https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16621

Isn't it possible to put the "command && wait" into one task?

Comment: Thank you. I did think about combining Kerberos ticket creation and connection check in one script. It is probably possible but This means I can’t use built in task wait_for_connection and would need to script authentication using Kerberos ticket which is  probably doable . It’s s pity this is not possible out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to a process I just implemented to change the permissions in a directory recursively:

```
---
- set_fact:
    parent_path: "{{ parent_path | default(myoriginal_path) | dirname }}"

- name: Configure acl for {{ parent_path }}
  debug:
    msg: "{{ parent_path }}"

- name: Run this file until getting /
  include_tasks: "{{ _ansible_item_label }}.yml"
  when: parent_path != '/'
```